# Элемент управления типа UpDown

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

В *WinForms* есть стандартный контрол [`NumericUpDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspxhttp://):

[image: NumericUpDown]

Хочется получить такой же, но без поля ввода. Т.е. по сути нужны только кнопки вверх/вниз. Понятно, что можно сляпать свой из двух кнопок и с изображением стрелок, но хотелось бы унификации со стандартным, чтобы на разных машинах или при смене настроек интерфейса пользователя мой контрол и стандартный выглядели единообразно.

Какие шаги следует предпринять для достижения нужного эффекта?

Comment: За отрисовку кнопок в этом контроле отвечает [UpDownButtons](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,1361). Можно попробовать сделать что-то на его основе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте унаследоваться от предка `NumericUpDown`: [`UpDownBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.updownbase(v=vs.110).aspx) и лимитировать размер контрола размером области кнопок:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Drawing;

public class UpDownControl : UpDownBase
{
    private readonly Control upDownButtons;

    public UpDownControl()
    {
        // Достаем internal свойство UpDownButtonsInternal
        var prop = GetType().GetProperty("UpDownButtonsInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (prop != null)
            upDownButtons = (Control)prop.GetValue(this, null);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        int gapWidth = Width - upDownButtons.Right + 1; // Либо const int gapWidth = 2;
        Size = new Size(upDownButtons.Width + gapWidth, upDownButtons.Height);
    }

    public override void DownButton()
    {
    }

    public override void UpButton()
    {
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
    }
}
```

События нажатий на кнопки будут прилетать в методы `DownButton` и `UpButton` соответственно.

Comment: Почти то что надо, но, к сожалению, почти. Обрезанная рамка дело портит. С левой стороны видно этот артефакт. Ну и пару `using` надо в код добавить для удобства копи-пасты `System.Reflection`, `System.Windows.Forms;`.

Comment: @alexolut Да, знаю про артефакт. Я нарочно не стал усложнять код, Нужно просто добавить пару пикселей к ширине. Обновил ответ.